# soft keyboard hides my edittext - android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, scrollview

I have an edittext inside my layout but when this edittext is clicked, the soft keyboard comes up and covers the entire text field. As a result, I can't see what I'm typing and it's very annoying. Can anyone tell me if there's a way to solve this?

EDIT: I also tried to wrap the entire layout in a scroll view. I heard in that way I can get what I want but still nothing happens. Here is the code of my layout:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <RelativeLayout 
       android:id="@+id/mainLayoutMain"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/background"
       android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
       android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

.................... Bunch of View....................
     </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

What else can I do?

P.S I tried also to set these attributes in my manifest file:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

and:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

and even:

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

But nothing works. Everthing leads to the same result - the soft keyboard hides the edit text field.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to make your root (parent) layout have `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, this way the `View` will invalidate itself when soft keyboard is summoned, resize accordingly and if the `EditText` is aligned to bottom of this `View` (I recommend you use `RelativeLayout` as parent for this reason), it should raise aswell.

---

**EDIT:**

Another thing:

Try setting this property into your manifest:

```
<application ... >
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" ... >
        ...
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

And then change your root layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:background="@drawable/background_grey"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

<!-- Your Layout content here -->

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I dont know about any other solution, mainly due to the fact that there is no known callback, or event of sorts to handle such behaviour in code (soft keyboard spawn).

So it all lies down to layout design and properties, and how the android system handles Input events depending on that.

Comment: I tried to set wrap_content in my relative layout but all the views just got messed up. Is there any way to do that without mess up the current layout?

Comment: @user3889576 You will have to change child view's properties to sort them out under new parent height attribute. I suggest you use relative positioning (aligning them towards parent bounds, or relative positions with android:layout_above="@+id/viewname"/android:layout_below="@+id/viewname"). Sadly, as I explained, there doesn't seem to be another solution for this problem, I faced a similar issue and end up relativizing the whole layout so that it reacts to soft keyboard.

Comment: I just tried to set wrap_content again and to organize all the views but still the soft keyboard keep hiding the text field. Is there another way to implement this?

Comment: Listen I did exactly what you said but it still won't scroll down. I tried to add the attributes you had wrote but still nothing happens. The text field is still hidden by the keyboard

Comment: @SuppressWarnings I tried your suggestion and it worked at first. The edit text field moved above. But when I hide the keyboard and showed it again, it didn't move and keyboard started covering edit text field :(. Any solution ?